# Is it possible to open MS OneNote files under Linux?

Tags: microsoft-office

Is it possible to open MS OneNote files under Linux?

At least read-only?

Comment: There is online OneNote version. You can open it there. You can install onenote using wine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of there existing a program that supports the OneNote file formats, but the specifications are published:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-onestore/ae670cd2-4b38-4b24-82d1-87cfb2cc3725?WT.mc_id
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-one/73d22548-a613-4350-8c23-07d15576be50?WT.mc_id

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is to move the OneNote files to OneDrive. You can do this with the link on [this site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-and-import-onenote-notebooks-a4b60da5-8f33-464e-b1ba-b95ce540f309). Be aware that Firefox won't work, I had to download Edge for a successful import.

After importing the file, you can open the notebook in the cloud version of OneNote.